# How can i set a tab from being edited, i lock a tab , so that any program running can't modify an opened file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If i have an opened file and let's say for example, i am runing the same files in android studio, if the file get modified vscode prevents it.

Is there settings for that ?.

Comment: make the file read-only by the OS